# Alternative for CSI ETABS

Tags: software-recommendation

Hi I just wanted now an alternative for ETABS program in Ubuntu . ETABS is a civil engineering program that design and analyse steel and concrete structures using finite element method.

There is more information [here](http://www.csiberkeley.com/etabs)